# tikz code compilation errors between different texlive version

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, subfloats, mactex, texlive-2023

As part of book that I'm working on, one chapter has several drawings  that were drawn in tikz some 8 years back. Many people in this forum helped with that effort including [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)

I am now trying to get the same code compiled in a new computer that has 2023 version of texlive (MacTex) where errors are cropping up in tikz. For reference, I have 2 computers: one running a 2015 version of texlive where everything works, and a newer PC which runs the[image] 2023 version of MacTex. Both computers are Mac OS. I've come up with a MWE example, which unfortunately is long and pasted below.

Any pointers to resolve this would be helpful. It appears something has changed in tikz or the operation of subfigure has changed between 2015 and 2023

**Desired output:**

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol} % just to get narrow columns on one page
\usepackage{polyglossia} % the multilingual support package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{dblfnote}
\DFNalwaysdouble

\setdefaultlanguage{english} % this is mostly going to be English text, with
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX, Scale=0.9]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt} % 1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}
\newcommand*{\Largerdot}{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\scalebox{1.1}{.}}}
\newcommand*{\Ldot}{\raisebox{1ex}{\scalebox{1.1}{.}}}
\newcommand{\du}[1]{$\overset{\Largerdot}{\mbox{{#1}}}$}  %% centrally align
\newcommand{\dl}[1]{$\underset{\Ldot}{\mbox{{#1}}}$}  %% centrally align


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% These are the core tikz functions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tikzset{
  myshape/.style 2 args={
    inner sep=0pt,
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=#1,
    minimum size=#2
  }
}

\newcommand\DrawShape[3]{
  \node[draw,myshape={#1}{#2},thick] (inner) {};
  \node[draw,myshape={#1}{#3},thick] (outer) {};
  \node[myshape={#1}{0.5*#3+0.5*#2}] (in) {};
  \node[myshape={#1}{#3+40pt}] (outside) {};
  \node[myshape={#1}{#2-40pt}] (inside) {};
  \foreach \Value in {1,...,#1}
  {
    \draw[thick]  (inner.corner \Value) -- (outer.corner \Value);
  }  
}

\newcommand\LabelsIn[3]{
  \foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {}
  \foreach \Value [count=\Num,evaluate=\Value as \Parts using \Value/\Total] in {1,...,\numexpr\Total-1\relax}
  {
    \draw[thick] 
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- 
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
  }
  \foreach \Text [count=\Num,evaluate=\Text as \Parts using (\Num/\Total)-1/(2*\Total)] in {#1} 
  {
    \path[]
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- node {\Text}
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
  }
}

\newcommand\LabelsInside[3]{
  \foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {}
  \foreach \Text [count=\Num,evaluate=\Text as \Parts using (\Num/\Total)-1/(2*\Total)] in {#1} 
  {
    \path[]
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- node[pos=-0.4] {\Text}
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
  }
}

\newcommand\LabelsOutside[3]{
  \foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {}
  \foreach \Text [count=\Num,evaluate=\Text as \Parts using (\Num/\Total)-1/(2*\Total)] in {#1} 
  {
    \path[]
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- node[pos=1.4] {\Text}
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
  }
}

% The non-standard FUNCTIONS
%

\newcommand\FirstShape[2]{%
% The basic shape
\draw[very thick] 
  (70:4) arc(70:275:4) -- 
  (270:3) arc(270:75:3) -- 
  (70:4) to[out=-90,in=110] 
  (45:2) to[out=-120,in=110]
  (0:1.5) to[out=-120,in=110]
  (-50:2) to[out=-130,in=80]
  (275:4) --
  (270:3) to[out=80,in=-130]
  (-60:1.3) to[out=110,in=-120]
  (20:0.85) to[out=110,in=-120]
  (60:1.8) to[out=110,in=-90]
  (75:3)
  (45:2) -- (60:1.8)
  (0:1.5) -- (20:0.85)
  (-50:2) -- (-60:1.3);
% The numbers inside
\foreach \Value [evaluate=\Value as \Step using {\Value*200/#1} ] in  {1,...,#1}
  { 
    \ifdim\dimexpr275pt-\Step pt\relax=75 pt\relax
    \else
      \draw[very thick]  ({275-\Step}:4) -- ++(275-\Step:-1);
      \node at ({275-\Step}:2.7) {\the\numexpr\Value+1\relax};
    \fi
  }  
\node[left] at (270:2.7) {1};
\node[left] at (73:2.7) {\the\numexpr#1+1\relax};
\node[left=2pt] at (60:1.8) {\the\numexpr#1+2\relax};
\node[left=2pt] at (20:0.85) {\the\numexpr#1+3\relax};
\node[left=2pt] at (-60:1.3) {\the\numexpr#1+4\relax};
% The texts outside
\foreach \Text [count=\Value,evaluate=\Value as \Step using {\Value*200/#1} ] in  {#2}
  \node at ({275-\Step}:4.5) {\Text}; 
\foreach \Text [
  count=\Value,
  evaluate=\Value as \Step using {\Value*200/#1} 
  ] in  {#2}
  {
    \node at ({275-\Step}:4.5) {\Text};
  }
% The constant texts in the right part
\node[right=2pt] at (70:4) {\sktuni{śa}};
\node[right=2pt] at (45:2) {\sktuni{vi}};
\node[right=2pt] at (0:1.5) {\sktuni{śa}};
\node[right=2pt] at (-50:2) {\sktuni{vi}};
\node[below=2pt] at (270:4) {\sktuni{śa}};
}

%%% END OF TIKZ FUNCTIONS


\begin{document}

% page 293
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawShape{4}{8cm}{12cm}
\LabelsIn{,}{1}{2}
\LabelsInside{1}{1}{2}
\LabelsOutside{{{sannipāta}}}{1}{2}
\LabelsIn{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsInside{4}{2}{3}
\LabelsOutside{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsIn{\du{S},|}{3}{4}
\LabelsInside{3}{3}{4}
\LabelsOutside{{{śamya}},{{tāla}}}{3}{4}
\LabelsIn{,S}{4}{1}
\LabelsInside{2}{4}{1}
\LabelsOutside{,{{śamya}}}{4}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
\centering
% 293-2
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawShape{4}{8cm}{12cm}
\LabelsIn{,}{1}{2}
\LabelsInside{1}{1}{2}
\LabelsOutside{{{śamya}}}{1}{2}
\LabelsIn{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsInside{4}{2}{3}
\LabelsOutside{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsIn{\du{S},|}{3}{4}
\LabelsInside{3}{3}{4}
\LabelsOutside{{{tāla}},{{śamya}}}{3}{4}
\LabelsIn{,S}{4}{1}
\LabelsInside{2}{4}{1}
\LabelsOutside{,{{tāla}}}{4}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
\centering
% 293-3
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawShape{4}{8cm}{12cm}
\LabelsIn{,}{1}{2}
\LabelsInside{1}{1}{2}
\LabelsOutside{{{tāla}}}{1}{2}
\LabelsIn{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsInside{4}{2}{3}
\LabelsOutside{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsIn{\du{S},|}{3}{4}
\LabelsInside{3}{3}{4}
\LabelsOutside{{{śamya}},{{tāla}}}{3}{4}
\LabelsIn{,S}{4}{1}
\LabelsInside{2}{4}{1}
%\LabelsOutside{,{\Large\sktuni{śamya}}}{4}{1}
\LabelsOutside{,{{śamya}}}{4}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Error tail**

```
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 141.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Value /\Total 
                          
l.163 }
```

The error happens at the end of subfigure block:

```
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: Observe that in `LabelsIn` the first `foreach` does nothing since there is an empty pair of braces at the end of line: `\foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {}`.

Comment: So `\Total` is undefined inside the next loop. The closing bracket at the end of the line @Sigur mentioned needs to go after the following loop.

Comment: Thanks @Sigur. The compilation problem is resolved. Now I have a new problem. There are few extra labels on the outside for each figure. It is due to looping logic that may need to be refined

Comment: Can you explain what you're drawing and how much variations there are to your diagram you need to control? It just seems like some rectangles, lines and a few nodes in some specific places. That's a lot of macros and loops for that that, in my opinion, could controlled maybe better. I don't think you're using `\FirstShape` at all.

Comment: So is it always a polygon ring where each side is divided in two (or more?) segments with a “label” in the middle and on the outside for each segment but also possibly for each side?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel There are a total of 44 shapes: rectangles, triangles, circle, semi-circle, weird polygon - and within each divisions etc. I wish there was way to share. I'm writing a book and these are shapes being transcribed. If someone could explain why the code "as is" worked well in 2015 texlive version. I've a neatly compiled version on the older computer with 2015 texlive. In particular the outer loop logic used in `FirstShape` was working well with `\foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {}`