# confused with tikz looping logic

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, foreach, for-loop

In an earlier question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698178/tikz-code-compilation-errors-between-different-texlive-version) and resolved partially, an extra cycle of execution within this function happens. As a result, there are extra labels published. Any idea what loop logic needs to be corrected?

See attached the incorrect version here (errors in red): [image]

The expected version is: [image]

What is the command to print out some counter and data that's flowing through in each loop into the final output as raw data? This may be elementary to tikz experts.

I appreciate your response. Thanks!

Here's the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol} % just to get narrow columns on one page
\usepackage{polyglossia} % the multilingual support package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{dblfnote}
\DFNalwaysdouble

\setdefaultlanguage{english} % this is mostly going to be English text, with
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX, Scale=0.9]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt} % 1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}
\newcommand*{\Largerdot}{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\scalebox{1.1}{.}}}
\newcommand*{\Ldot}{\raisebox{1ex}{\scalebox{1.1}{.}}}
\newcommand{\du}[1]{$\overset{\Largerdot}{\mbox{{#1}}}$}  %% centrally align
\newcommand{\dl}[1]{$\underset{\Ldot}{\mbox{{#1}}}$}  %% centrally align


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% These are the core tikz functions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tikzset{
  myshape/.style 2 args={
    inner sep=0pt,
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=#1,
    minimum size=#2
  }
}

\newcommand\DrawShape[3]{
  \node[draw,myshape={#1}{#2},thick] (inner) {};
  \node[draw,myshape={#1}{#3},thick] (outer) {};
  \node[myshape={#1}{0.5*#3+0.5*#2}] (in) {};
  \node[myshape={#1}{#3+40pt}] (outside) {};
  \node[myshape={#1}{#2-40pt}] (inside) {};
  \foreach \Value in {1,...,#1}
  {
    \draw[thick]  (inner.corner \Value) -- (outer.corner \Value);
  }  
}

\newcommand\LabelsIn[3]{
  \foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {
  \foreach \Value [count=\Num,evaluate=\Value as \Parts using \Value/\Total] in {1,...,\numexpr\Total-1\relax}
    \draw[thick] 
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- 
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
  \foreach \Text [count=\Num,evaluate=\Text as \Parts using (\Num/\Total)-1/(2*\Total)] in {#1} 
    \path[]
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- node {\Text}
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
}
}

\newcommand\LabelsInside[3]{
  \foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {
  \foreach \Text [count=\Num,evaluate=\Text as \Parts using (\Num/\Total)-1/(2*\Total)] in {#1} 
    \path[]
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- node[pos=-0.4] {\Text}
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
}
}

\newcommand\LabelsOutside[3]{
  \foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {
  \foreach \Text [count=\Num,evaluate=\Text as \Parts using (\Num/\Total)-1/(2*\Total)] in {#1} 
    \path[]
      ( $ (inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3) $ ) -- node[pos=1.4] {\Text}
      ( $ (outer.corner #2)!($(inner.corner #2)!\Parts!(inner.corner #3)$)!(outer.corner #3) $ );
}
}

% The non-standard FUNCTIONS
%

\newcommand\FirstShape[2]{%
% The basic shape
\draw[very thick] 
  (70:4) arc(70:275:4) -- 
  (270:3) arc(270:75:3) -- 
  (70:4) to[out=-90,in=110] 
  (45:2) to[out=-120,in=110]
  (0:1.5) to[out=-120,in=110]
  (-50:2) to[out=-130,in=80]
  (275:4) --
  (270:3) to[out=80,in=-130]
  (-60:1.3) to[out=110,in=-120]
  (20:0.85) to[out=110,in=-120]
  (60:1.8) to[out=110,in=-90]
  (75:3)
  (45:2) -- (60:1.8)
  (0:1.5) -- (20:0.85)
  (-50:2) -- (-60:1.3);
% The numbers inside
\foreach \Value [evaluate=\Value as \Step using {\Value*200/#1} ] in  {1,...,#1}
  { 
    \ifdim\dimexpr275pt-\Step pt\relax=75 pt\relax
    \else
      \draw[very thick]  ({275-\Step}:4) -- ++(275-\Step:-1);
      \node at ({275-\Step}:2.7) {\the\numexpr\Value+1\relax};
    \fi
  }  
\node[left] at (270:2.7) {1};
\node[left] at (73:2.7) {\the\numexpr#1+1\relax};
\node[left=2pt] at (60:1.8) {\the\numexpr#1+2\relax};
\node[left=2pt] at (20:0.85) {\the\numexpr#1+3\relax};
\node[left=2pt] at (-60:1.3) {\the\numexpr#1+4\relax};
% The texts outside
\foreach \Text [count=\Value,evaluate=\Value as \Step using {\Value*200/#1} ] in  {#2}
  \node at ({275-\Step}:4.5) {\Text}; 
\foreach \Text [
  count=\Value,
  evaluate=\Value as \Step using {\Value*200/#1} 
  ] in  {#2}
  {
    \node at ({275-\Step}:4.5) {\Text};
  }
% The constant texts in the right part
\node[right=2pt] at (70:4) {\sktuni{śa}};
\node[right=2pt] at (45:2) {\sktuni{vi}};
\node[right=2pt] at (0:1.5) {\sktuni{śa}};
\node[right=2pt] at (-50:2) {\sktuni{vi}};
\node[below=2pt] at (270:4) {\sktuni{śa}};
}

%%% END OF TIKZ FUNCTIONS


\begin{document}

% page 293
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawShape{4}{8cm}{12cm}
\LabelsIn{,}{1}{2}
\LabelsInside{1}{1}{2}
\LabelsOutside{{{sannipāta}}}{1}{2}
\LabelsIn{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsInside{4}{2}{3}
\LabelsOutside{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsIn{\du{S},|}{3}{4}
\LabelsInside{3}{3}{4}
\LabelsOutside{śamya,tāla}{3}{4}
\LabelsIn{,S}{4}{1}
\LabelsInside{2}{4}{1}
\LabelsOutside{,{{śamya}}}{4}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
\centering
% 293-2
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawShape{4}{8cm}{12cm}
\LabelsIn{,}{1}{2}
\LabelsInside{1}{1}{2}
\LabelsOutside{{{śamya}}}{1}{2}
\LabelsIn{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsInside{4}{2}{3}
\LabelsOutside{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsIn{\du{S},|}{3}{4}
\LabelsInside{3}{3}{4}
\LabelsOutside{{{tāla}},{{śamya}}}{3}{4}
\LabelsIn{,S}{4}{1}
\LabelsInside{2}{4}{1}
\LabelsOutside{,{{tāla}}}{4}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
\centering
% 293-3
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\DrawShape{4}{8cm}{12cm}
\LabelsIn{,}{1}{2}
\LabelsInside{1}{1}{2}
\LabelsOutside{{{tāla}}}{1}{2}
\LabelsIn{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsInside{4}{2}{3}
\LabelsOutside{,}{2}{3}
\LabelsIn{\du{S},|}{3}{4}
\LabelsInside{3}{3}{4}
\LabelsOutside{{{śamya}},{{tāla}}}{3}{4}
\LabelsIn{,S}{4}{1}
\LabelsInside{2}{4}{1}
\LabelsOutside{,{{śamya}}}{4}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the same variable for both nested loops: `\Text`.

Comment: You can use `\typeout` to write any text to the log file. You can put everything into it except the `\path` to figure out what paths you actually commanding. Besides what @Sigur said, why are you nested looping over `#1` twice? The `count` key isn't counting the total number of entries in the list. (Well, it has for the last entry but it just counts up from 1.)

Comment: Please don't post snippets of code. Questions should include complete minimal examples which people can compile to reproduce the problem you're asking about. Don't rely on links to other questions, even your own. Instead, write a self-contained question and link the other (as you have), even if it means repetition.

Comment: @cfr please see the MWE that I added to my question

Comment: Thanks for adding code, but please remove whatever isn't needed to demonstrate the problem. As others have said, you can't use the same variable for two loops if one is nested inside the other. So you need to change e.g. one of the `\Text` to some other name.

Comment: I used a different variable for the second loop. Still no behavior change. It is the first loop `\foreach \Text [count=\Total] in {#1} {}`  as was written originally, extracts `\Text` and is used in the second loop. Note that loop was empty but was serving some purpose that I don't understand.  With 2023 texlive version, this `foreach` loop required that loop to encapsulate the succeeding `foreach` loop. I'm not able to follow as I'm just a custodian trying to recompile after many years. In the worst case, I will have to maintain an older version of texlive going. Thanks